# AugmentedImageDatabase Arcore: add multiple images

Tags: java, android, arcore

I have folder with images, but i cant add them to database. They have specific names. App says "AR session failed" This is my code:

```
  public void setupDatabase(Config config, Session session)
    {
        String filepath = getIntent().getStringExtra("filepath");
        Log.d ("AID", "Veriable:" + filepath);
        File dir = new File (filepath);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        AugmentedImageDatabase aid = new AugmentedImageDatabase(session);

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            if (files[i].getName().startsWith("arimage"))
            {
                String filename = files[i].getName ();
                Log.d ("AID", "FileName:" + files[i].getName ());
                Bitmap arcontentBitmap =loadAugmentedImage(files[i]);
                Log.d ("AID", "Files:" + files[i].getPath ());
                String imagename = filename.substring(0, filename.length() - 4);
                Log.d ("AID", "NameImage:" + imagename);

                aid.addImage(imagename, arcontentBitmap);

            }

        }
        config.setAugmentedImageDatabase(aid);
    }
```

Method loadAugmentedImage

```
private Bitmap loadAugmentedImage(File file)
    {
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream (file))
        {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("ImageLoad", "IO Exception", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed a size of buffer from 1024 to 4096 of downloaded file and unzip method. I put a full path of images to my Method loadAugmentedImage.

```
public void setupDatabase(Config config, Session session) 
{
        AugmentedImageDatabase aid = new AugmentedImageDatabase(session);
        Intent intent = getIntent ();
        String filepath = intent.getStringExtra ("filepath");
        Log.d ("AID", "Veriable:" + filepath);
        File directory = new File (filepath);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles ();
        Log.d ("AID", "Size: " + files.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {

            if (files[i].getName().startsWith("arimage"))
            {
                String filename = files[i].getName ();
                Log.d ("AID", "FileName:" + filename);
                Bitmap arcontentBitmap = loadAugmentedImage(files[i].getPath ());
                Log.d ("AID", "FilePath:" + files[i].getPath ());
                Log.d ("AID", "Files:" + files[i].getAbsolutePath ());
                String imagename = filename.substring(0, filename.length() - 4);
                Log.d ("AID", "NameImage:" + imagename);
                aid.addImage(imagename, arcontentBitmap);
            }
        }
        config.setAugmentedImageDatabase(aid);
}
```

Method loadAugmentedImage

```
private Bitmap loadAugmentedImage(String file)
    {
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream (file))
        {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("loadAugmentedImage", "IO Exception", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any clue for loading images from URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `InputStream is = new FileInputStream (file)` with `InputStream is = getAssets().open(file)`

I see, that you create new image database and than load all of the images. It is not good practice, because loading one image takes about 30 ms. So if you need all of those images from the beginning, than you should load image database at compile time. You should use [arcoreimg](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/arcoreimg) to create database, this option also have option to set size of image in real world, which helps with detection. Than only load the database with:

```
AugmentedImageDatabase augmentedImageDatabase = new AugmentedImageDatabase(session);
    try(InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("imgdatabase.imgdb")){
        augmentedImageDatabase = AugmentedImageDatabase.deserialize(session, inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IO exception loading augmented image database.", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    config.setAugmentedImageDatabase(augmentedImageDatabase);
```

But don't load images you don't need at the beginning of the app. Because your app will try to detect all images and that can have big impact on performance.

Comment: Is it possible to create database with arcoreimg on backend? And after creating download and load imgdatabase.imgdb to app

Comment: I don't know. Probably yes, because there is linux version of arcoreimg and your backend should be able to execute linux comands. Also load generated file from memory and send it. Android can receive it and use as inputStream. But as i said i don't know this is just my thoughts.